# SSRS: This Page Could Not Be Found

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have walked into an already setup instance of SSRS and am trying to help troubleshoot an issue for a new user.  When the user attempts to connect to the URL (i.e. http://myServerName/Reports), she gets a "This page could not be found" error in the browser.  As of now, this only appears to be happening for this one user.

I am not quite sure if this error is occurring because of a Report Manager permissions issue, or because of a server permissions issue.  Does anyone have any ideas on what security/permissions settings I can check on either side to see why this one user cannot access the site?

Comment: If it's over a local network , she might not be part of it.

Comment: Two things to check. First, can you user ping the server address at all. If they can't it is a networking issue. If they can ping the server, and you have verified that they are using the correct url that works for others, then you might be looking at a permissions issue, but in that case you usually get a different error.